# "Malformed JSON" from http get request

Tags: java, android, json

I get some data on an URL. There's my server script :

```
    $db = null;
$results = "{}";

require_once("connect.php");

/* Query */
if($db != null) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT category, category_color FROM categories ORDER BY category");
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

/* Close db connection */
$db = null;

echo json_encode($results);
```

Soooo.. I get theses datas on my Android App. This is what my App get from the script :

```
    [{"category":"Animals","category_color":"green"},
{"category":"Art","category_color":"orange"},
{"category":"Sport","category_color":"blue"},
{"category":"Video games","category_color":"red"}]
```

And there's my App code, to get my datas (this is my first App so some code found on Internet helped me) :

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0];
    String parsedString;
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(this.timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                //Do stuff to parse my JSON to an HashMap
        }

    } catch(IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've tried a lot of stuff to parse theses datas into a HashMap ([category, category_color] for each element) like this :

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

I found this result everytime for each response on Stack. But when I tried this code, my console has printed : **E/JSON Task: Cound not parse malformed JSON** when I try to do : "**JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);**

So, there is my final question :

What is the best way to get an HashMap from a JSON get from my php script ? A simple link can be useful, but at the moment, I can't found a clean working answer.

Comment: the string you posted is a jsonarray not a jsonobject.

Comment: Oh god man, I feel idiot, I didn't know the difference. How can I parse it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to get data from php script is to create array

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "category": "Animals",
      "category_color": "green"
    },
    {
      "category": "Art",
      "category_color": "orange"
    }
  ]
}
```

you can get data in above format by following script

```
$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT category, category_color FROM categories ORDER BY category"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['category'] = $row[0];
    $row_array['category_color'] = $row[1]; 


    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

prase data by following code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); // here response is what you get from php script which is shown at top 
JSONArray message = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                    Model model = new Model();
                    JSONObject temp = message.getJSONObject(i);
                    String category = temp.getString("category");
                    String category_color = temp.getString("category_color");


// create array or harshmap to store all data

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
```

since your received data is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON parsing tools Gson or Jackson its save your time